# TFS 2012 and SSMS 2012

Tags: tfs, ssms-2012

I have been trying for the last 12 hours to add items to a TFS Team Project using SSMS 2012, has anyone else experienced this issue?

I am able to add items using SSMS 2008-R2 without any issues.

In SSMS 2008-R2 when I wanted to create a new Project I would simply select File → New → Project. I would then type in the name of the project, make sure that the Add to Source Control checkbox was selected and after a few seconds the Check in - Source Files form magically appeared. Then I would check the Check-In button the project was automatically created (neat huh??).

However in SSMS 2012, I follow the same steps and Nothing happens other than the project being added magically to the Solution explorer. Now, I checked to make sure that the settings were identically between both SSMS 2008-R2 and SSMS 2012 and they appear to be. Both applications are hitting the same exact TFS server so for now I think that it is "off the hook".

Please give me your ideas on what or where I should look.

Answer (score 3):

A similar thread on the DBA portion of Stack Exchange that may be of some help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17850/tfs2010-for-ssms-2012

Comment: Thanks, I found that link prior to my post. It appears that there is a known issue involving SSMS 2012 and TFS: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16097/no-such-interface-supported-after-upgrading-sourcesafe-project-to-2012-ssms-fo